# Javascript: can't re-assign variable within recursive function call

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion, global-variables

In the following code I'm checking to see if a string of characters is "spellable" in a certain grid, similar to Scrabble. Letters can be used if they are directly above, below, left, or right of the current letter. For example, "bcd" should return TRUE, while "bcdn" should return FALSE.

The functions execute exactly as I expect, *except* for on lines 32-33. From my understanding the `wordExists = true` line should override the original declaration on line 9.

What am I missing?

repl.it link = http://repl.it/Yhh/5

```
var grid = [
    ['a','b','c','d'],
    ['e','f','g','h'],
    ['i','j','k','l'],
    ['m','n','o','p']
];

function doesWordExist(word, grid) {
    var wordExists = false;
    for (var i = 0, end = grid.length; i < end; i++){
        for (var j = 0, stop = grid[0].length; j < stop; j++) {
            if (word[0] === grid[i][j]) {
                doesLetterExist(word, i, j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return wordExists;
}

function isMatch(letter,i,j) {
    return (
        grid[i] !== undefined && 
        grid[i][j] !== undefined &&
        letter === grid[i][j]
    );
}

function doesLetterExist(word, i, j, depth) {
    console.log('i:' +i + " - j:" + j);
    var letter = word[depth];
    if (letter === undefined) {
        wordExists = true;
        console.log('can\'t re-define global "wordExists" variable :-(');
    }
    if (isMatch(letter,i, j + 1)) { // look right, j + 1
        doesLetterExist(word, i, j + 1, depth + 1);
    } else if (isMatch(letter, i, j -1)) { // look left, j - 1
        doesLetterExist(word, i, j - 1, depth + 1);
    } else if (isMatch(letter, i - 1, j)) { // look up, i - 1
        doesLetterExist(word, i - 1, j, depth + 1);
    } else if (isMatch(letter, i + 1, j)) { // look down, i + 1
        doesLetterExist(word, i + 1, j, depth + 1);
    }
}

doesWordExist('bcd', grid);
```

Thanks!

Edit: I removed the word 'global' from the title. I mistakenly referred to a variable instantiated in the first function as global. It should be available and changeable from all functions within it's scope right? That is what I was referring to with 'global', it feels global to all child functions.

Comment: You could refactor your algorithm to not rely on a global variable.

Comment: `function doesWordExist(word, grid) {
    var wordExists = false;` <-- not global

Comment: `if (letter === undefined) {
        wordExists = true;`  <-- is actually global

Comment: epascarello, Thanks for your comments. Here is a boiled down version of what I don't understand. I thought that a variable assignment would look into it's parent function's scope before declaring a global variable.

http://repl.it/Yi5/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should be available and changeable from all functions within it's scope right? It feels global to all child functions.

Yes. Only that `isMatch` and `doesLetterExist` are no child functions of `doesWordExist`! They are declared outside of its body. We need to **nest** them them so that they get access to their parent scope:

```
function doesWordExist(word, grid) {
    var wordExists = false;
    for (var i = 0, end = grid.length; i < end; i++){
        for (var j = 0, stop = grid[0].length; j < stop; j++) {
            if (word[0] === grid[i][j]) {
                doesLetterExist(word, i, j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return wordExists;

    function doesLetterExist(word, i, j, depth) {
        console.log('i:' +i + " - j:" + j);
        var letter = word[depth];
        if (letter === undefined) {
            wordExists = true;
        }
        if (isMatch(i, j + 1)) { // look right, j + 1
            doesLetterExist(word, i, j + 1, depth + 1);
        } else if (isMatch(i, j -1)) { // look left, j - 1
            doesLetterExist(word, i, j - 1, depth + 1);
        } else if (isMatch( i - 1, j)) { // look up, i - 1
            doesLetterExist(word, i - 1, j, depth + 1);
        } else if (isMatch(i + 1, j)) { // look down, i + 1
            doesLetterExist(word, i + 1, j, depth + 1);
        }
        function isMatch(i, j) {
            return grid[i] !== undefined && 
                   grid[i][j] !== undefined &&
                   letter === grid[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly the `isMatch` function can now access the `letter` variable as it is part of the `doesLetterExist` function, it doesn't need to be passed as an argument any more.

---

However, while your function would now work, it is still not optimal. When `wordExists` is set to true, you should be able to break out of `doesWordExist` - you know the solution already. Currently, you're continuing to loop - and it is a quite heavy loop. Try to improve your original algorithm (with 3 separate functions) so that you don't have that "global" `wordExists` variable, but instead use only **`return` values** in each function - `doesLetterExist` should immediately `return true` when it has found the letter, and return `false` only after it has sifted through all recursive calls.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. I erroneously thought that simply calling a function within another was enough to get access to their parent function's scopes. I understand now that the function has to be declared and called within any parent function if it wishes to capture that parent function's scope. And very good recommendation about the optimizations. I've taken your points and refactored the code ([http://repl.it/Yhh/7](http://repl.it/Yhh/7)). Thanks again for your help with this!

Answer (score 2):

You defined wordExists as a local variable on line 9

```
var wordExists = false;
```

Take out `var` from the above

Comment: Taking it out will lead to a "working" script, but it's not a good solution. Can't you suggest something better?

Comment: @Bergi The OP specifically asked about global variables so I am assuming there's a reason he needs it to be in that context

Comment: @Bergi is right, although I should have been clearer. I'd like for all of the variables to be self-container within the functions. I've updated the original post.